# Angular JS using Grunt: Display images from local folder using relative path from JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, gruntjs

So I am using a JSON that returns a lot of data about the user including pictures. The problem I am facing is that I believe the relative path to the images folder is correct however for some reason it is saying in `ng-source="relativePath"` instead of the image. The only conclusion I can come to is either the path is wrong or there is some sort of import I must do for the images to be used in the project.

```
<div ng-repeat="results in userInfo.images">
  <figure class="img">
    <img data-ng-source="{{results.imageUrl}}" ng-alt="{{results.name}}" ng-title="{{results.name}}" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

I have tried source, ng-source, and data-ng-source. When I view in console and on the html for image src it shows the relative path `/images/profilePicture.png`.

My project has the following structure:

```
Repositry Name
   app
   css
   home
     home.module.js
     home.tpl.html
   images
     profilePicture.png
   js
   resources
   app.js
   index.html
```

Using best practices the index.htlm is the container for the single page application. We are using the home.tpl.html page that is injected into the index.html container page.

I have tried switching the path to go directly from index.html -> `/images/profilePicture.png` as well as from home.tpl.html -> `../images/profilePicture.png`.

I could not find any posts relevant to my situation but I believe perhaps you need an app.use or some sort of injection method to add the folder of images to be able to be used?

**Note:** I am not sure if this is helpful however when I run grunt build instead of serve I check the **dist** folder and the image folder does in fact have all of the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `<img data-ng-source` declaration to just use `ng-src`:

```
<img ng-src="{{results.imageUrl}}" ng-alt="{{results.name}}" ng-title="{{results.name}}" />
```

More details at w3schools: [ng-src](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-src.asp)

Comment: Wow I was using ng-source before. Thanks :)